# Actively count instance in order, R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Name  Month
A     1
A     7
A     7
A     4
A     3
A    11
A    12
B     5
B     6
B    12
B     4
B     9
B    12
B    10
```

And I want to count the rank the month and group it by the Name. 
So I want it to look like this.

```
Name  Month Count
A     1       1  
A     7       4
A     7       5
A     4       2
A     3       3
A    11       6
A    12       7
B     5       2
B     6       3
B    12       6
B     4       1
B     9       4
B    12       7
B    10       5
```

I am trying to do this in R and I would really like to use dplyr.
Any suggestions?

**Edit**
I failed to mention that I would like the rank to be incremented even if there are duplicates. I updated the data to reflect the same thing.

Comment: This is just `rank` by group.  `ave` can help you do that.

Comment: *count the rank the month and group it by the Name*. This basically describes how you should do it already. `group_by()` and `rank()` functions are what you are looking for.

Comment: Since you don't have any ties it doesn't really matter which ranking function you use, but one option: `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Count = dense_rank(Month))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comments, you should pipeline `group_by` and some ranking function. Only the function giving desired output is `row_number`.

So I think it should look like this:

```
Name = c(rep('A', 7), rep('B', 7))
Month = c(1, 7, 7, 4, 3, 11, 12, 5, 6, 12, 4, 9, 12, 10)
Data = data.frame(Name, Month)

library(dplyr)

Data %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Count = row_number(Month))
```